# I need help solve my problem of my activity

Tags: c++

So I need my help to correct my code, which is given to my programming class assignment. My activity is to print numbers divisible by 5 for the integers from 1 to 99. So I tried to code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int num, min, max;
cout << "Enter Number: ";
cin >> num;
min = 1;
max = 99;
if (num > min || num < max) {
    if (num % 5 == 0) {
        cout << "Divisible.";}
    else {
        cout << "Not Divisible";}
        }
else { 
    if (num % 5 == 0) {
        cout << "Error Input.";}
    else {
        cout << "Error input.";}
    }
return 0;
}
```

So when I compile and run, I test to enter a divisible number by 5 or not. When I put 0, it says "Error input," that's correct. However, when I put 100, it says "divisible" instead of "error input." What is the correct input of my code?

Comment: You are not looping

Comment: The code shown here will print "Divisible" when given 0, 25 or 100.

Comment: Read a good [C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and the documentation of your C++ compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). With GCC, compile your code with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use `gdb` to understand the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is an integer from 1 to 99, which means that it should be >= 1 **AND** <= 99.

So, simply change

```c
if (num > min || num < max)
```

to

```c
if (num >= min && num <= max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in the first **if** statement. When you are giving the **OR** operator, it'll return true even if only one of the conditions are satisfied.

You should use the **AND** operator for your code to work as expected.

Moreover, you don't have to use the `min` and `max` variables also, it is making the program unnecessarily big (only 2 lines though, but still).